# Scalate and GAE Options org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateException: Unable to create temporary file

Tags: google-app-engine, scala, scalate

I am trying to run Scala/Scalate on Google app engine. 
I wanted to test the project so i am running the GAE locally its 
deployed successfully and when i try to call the main url i am getting 
following exception

> org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateException: Unable to create temporary 
>   file 
>           at 
>   org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.compileAndLoad(TemplateEngine.scala:
>   739) 
>           at 
>   org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.compileAndLoadEntry(TemplateEngine.sc
>   ala:  595) 
>           at 
>   org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.liftedTree1$1(TemplateEngine.scala:
>   327) 
>           at 
>   org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.load(TemplateEngine.scala:321) 
>           at 
>   org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.load(TemplateEngine.scala:391) 
>           at org.scalatra.scalate.ScalateSupport 
>   $class.renderErrorPage(ScalateSupport.scala:56) 
>           at MyScalatraFilter.renderErrorPage(MyScalatraFilter.scala:5) 
>           at org.scalatra.scalate.ScalateSupport 
>   $class.handleError(ScalateSupport.scala:51) 
>           at MyScalatraFilter.handleError(MyScalatraFilter.scala:5) 
>           at
>   org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$$anonfun$handle$1$$anonfun$apply 
>   $mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply$mcV$sp(ScalatraKernel.scala: 
>   140) 
>           at
>   org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$$anonfun$handle$1$$anonfun$apply 
>   $mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(ScalatraKernel.scala:134) 
>           at
>   org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$$anonfun$handle$1$$anonfun$apply 
>   $mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(ScalatraKernel.scala:134) 
>           at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:
>   71) 
>           at
>   org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$$anonfun$handle$1$$anonfun$apply 
>   $mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ScalatraKernel.scala:134) 
>           at
>   org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$$anonfun$handle$1$$anonfun$apply 
>   $mcV$sp$1.apply(ScalatraKernel.scala:134) 
>           at
>   org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$$anonfun$handle$1$$anonfun$apply 
>   $mcV$sp$1.apply(ScalatraKernel.scala:134) 
>           at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:
>   71) 
>           at org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$$anonfun$handle$1.apply$mcV 
>   $sp(ScalatraKernel.scala:133) 
>           at org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$$anonfun$handle 
>   $1.apply(ScalatraKernel.scala:133) 
>           at org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$$anonfun$handle 
>   $1.apply(ScalatraKernel.scala:133) 
>           at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:
>   71) 
>           at org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel 
>   $class.handle(ScalatraKernel.scala:132) 
>           at MyScalatraFilter.handle(MyScalatraFilter.scala:5) 
>           at org.scalatra.ScalatraFilter$$anonfun$doFilter$1.apply$mcV 
>   $sp(ScalatraFilter.scala:18) 
>           at org.scalatra.ScalatraFilter$$anonfun$doFilter 
>   $1.apply(ScalatraFilter.scala:18) 
>           at org.scalatra.ScalatraFilter$$anonfun$doFilter 
>   $1.apply(ScalatraFilter.scala:18) 
>           at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:
>   71) 
>           at org.scalatra.ScalatraFilter 
>   $class.doFilter(ScalatraFilter.scala:17) 
>           at MyScalatraFilter.doFilter(MyScalatraFilter.scala:5) 
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler 
>   $CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157) 
>           at 
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(He
>   aderVerificationFilter.java:  35) 
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler 
>   $CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157) 
>           at 
>   com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFi
>   lter.java:  58) 
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler 
>   $CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157) 
>           at 
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(Trans
>   actionCleanupFilter.java:  43) 
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler 
>   $CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157) 
>           at 
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFile
>   Filter.java:  122) 
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler 
>   $CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157) 
>           at 
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(Backen
>   dServersFilter.java:  97) 
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler 
>   $CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157) 
>           at 
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java: 
>   388) 
>           at 
>   org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:
>   216) 
>           at 
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java: 
>   182) 
>           at 
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java: 
>   765) 
>           at 
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418) 
>           at 
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEn
>   gineWebAppContext.java:  70) 
>           at 
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java: 
>   152) 
>           at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService 
>   $ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:351) 
>           at 
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java: 
>   152) 
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326) 
>           at 
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java: 
>   542) 
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection 
>   $RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923) 
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
>
> ```
>     at
> ```
>
> org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:  212) 
>           at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:  404) 
>           at 
>   org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:
>   409) 
>           at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool 
>   $PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)  Caused by:
>   java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to create temporary  file 
>           at java.io.File.checkAndCreate(File.java:1701) 
>           at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1792) 
>           at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1828) 
>           at 
>   org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.workingDirectory(TemplateEngine.scala
>   :  200) 
>           at 
>   org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.sourceDirectory(TemplateEngine.scala:
>   156) 
>           at 
>   org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.sourceFileName(TemplateEngine.scala:
>   612) 
>           at 
>   org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.compileAndLoad(TemplateEngine.scala:
>   650) 
>           ... 56 more  Aug 19, 2011 3:45:16 PM 
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet 
>   WARNING: No file found for: /favicon.ico

Anyone help me on this issues ?

Answer (score 0):

GAE has some multithreading restrictions, scalate user guide has notes about GAE with link to example project, [link to guide](http://scalate.fusesource.org/documentation/user-guide.html#Using_Scalate_on_GAE)

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific you need to precompile your templates, as the [documentation specifies](http://scalate.fusesource.org/documentation/user-guide.html#Using_Scalate_on_GAE).